# .scale() cancels out extend: function(options). How do I get these two to play well together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

Using Galleria 1-2-8, Classic theme.

I have..

```
$('#galleria').galleria({
    imageCrop: "false",
    thumbnails: 'lazy',
    carouselSteps: 1,
    transition: 'flash',
    transitionSpeed: 800,

    extend: function(options) {
        var gallery = this;

        this.bind(Galleria.IMAGE, function(e) {
            TONS OF CODE
        });
    }
});
```

Then beneath I have

```
Galleria.ready(function(options) {
    this.bind('image', function(e) {
        this.lazyLoadChunks( 3, 200 );
        this.scale();
    });
});
```

The line "this.scale();" is a new addition. The code was working fine before, but I had to force a rescale on the main image. The reason being, I have tweaked galleria massively, and I've encountered an issue where the thumbnail scrolling behaves very erratically. To fix the strange thumbnail behavior, I have simulated a click on the nav-right arrow div and a click on the nav-left arrow div at the bottom of Galleria.ready -- which I have not shown you in the above code.

```
$('.galleria-image-nav-right').click();
$('.galleria-image-nav-left').click();
```

The reason I chose to do this is because I noticed that when I, the user, clicked the next arrow for the main image, it fixed the thumbnail scrolling issue. So I force a click on the next image once Galleria has loaded, and then click back (while displaying a loading image over it all so the user does not notice).

ANYWAY.. when I call .scale() on the image, it overrides all the options I wrote in the first block of code up there. It cancels them out completely, as if they were never there. I've tested with alerts inside the code to see if the variables I set were still there, and they are not.

I've tried different methods.. .scale(), .refreshImage(), ._scaleImage(), etc, but they all reference eachother and all have the same problem of canceling out the extend: function(options) stuff.

Please help!

If this information is not enough, or you need to see my code in full, here it is..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Galleria.loadTheme('/js/galleria.classic.js');
            $('#galleria').galleria({
                imageCrop: "false",
                thumbnails: 'lazy',
                carouselSteps: 1,
                transition: 'flash',
                transitionSpeed: 800,

            extend: function(options) {
                var gallery = this;
                this.bind(Galleria.IMAGE, function(e) {


                    // $(window).resize(function() {
                        // this.scale();
                    // });//yep, tried it here.. no luck


                    var current = gallery.getData(gallery.getIndex());
                    var currImg = current.original;
                    var altText = $(currImg).attr('alt');
                    var src = $(currImg).attr('src');
                    var thehref = $(currImg).parent().attr('href');
                    var actualCurrent = $(currImg).parent();
                    getFFData(altText);

                    function getSource(val) {
                        var source = val;
                        while(source) {
                            if( n=source.indexOf("Vertical/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    $(".galleria-images img").removeClass();
                                    $(".galleria-images img").addClass("vertIMG");
                                    $("#galleria-bigImage-popup").addClass("vertDIV");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("right", "34.2%");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("top", "45%");
                                    $(".galleria-info").css("top", "94%");
                                    $(".galleria-info").css("display", "block");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("display", "block");
                                    $(".galleria-info-text").css("visibility", "visible");
                                    $(".galleria-info-text").fadeIn(800);
                                }
                            }
                            if( n=source.indexOf("Horizontal/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    $(".galleria-images img").removeClass();
                                    $(".galleria-images img").addClass("horizIMG");
                                    $("#galleria-bigImage-popup").addClass("horizDIV");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("right", "25.8%");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("top", "45%");
                                    $(".galleria-info").css("top", "94%");
                                    $(".galleria-info").css("display", "block");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("display", "block");
                                    $(".galleria-info-text").css("visibility", "visible");
                                    $(".galleria-info-text").fadeIn(800);
                                }
                            }
                            if( n=source.indexOf("Pano/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    $(".galleria-images img").removeClass();
                                    $(".galleria-images img").addClass("panoIMG");
                                    $("#galleria-bigImage-popup").addClass("panoDIV");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("right", "25.8%");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("top", "inherit");
                                    $(".galleria-info").css("top", "73%");
                                    $(".galleria-info").css("display", "block");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("display", "block");
                                    $(".galleria-info-text").css("visibility", "visible");
                                    $(".galleria-info-text").fadeIn(800);
                                }
                            }
                            if( n=source.indexOf("Pano-Tall/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    $(".galleria-images img").removeClass();
                                    $(".galleria-images img").addClass("panoTallIMG");
                                    $("#galleria-bigImage-popup").addClass("panoTallDIV");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("right", "25.8%");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("top", "inherit");
                                    $(".galleria-info").css("top", "84%");
                                    $(".galleria-info").css("display", "block");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("display", "block");
                                    $(".galleria-info-text").css("visibility", "visible");
                                    $(".galleria-info-text").fadeIn(800);

                                }
                            }
                            if( n=source.indexOf("Pano-Vert/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    $(".galleria-images img").removeClass();
                                    $(".galleria-images img").addClass("panoVertIMG");
                                    $("#galleria-bigImage-popup").addClass("panoVertDIV");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("right", "42.1%");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("top", "45%");
                                    $(".galleria-info").css("top", "94%");
                                    $(".galleria-info").css("display", "block");
                                    $(".galleria-info-title").css("display", "block");
                                    $(".galleria-info-text").css("visibility", "visible");
                                    $(".galleria-info-text").fadeIn(800);
                                }
                            }
                            return;
                        }//end while
                    }// end function getSource

                    getSource(thehref);
                    var newSrc = thehref.replace("sized","large"); //change contents of src variable to point to the large images dir.
                    getBigImage(newSrc);  //this function is located in the utils.js file

                    function bigImageResizer(val) {
                        var theA = val;//this works
                        var theImage = $(theA).find('img');//this works
                        var theSource = $(theImage).attr('src');//this works. same as var thehref
                        //how do I get the height of the IMAGE?

                        var winWidth = $(window).width();
                        var imgWidth = $(theImage).width();
                        // var widthToUse = winWidth - imgWidth;
                        // var widthToUse = winWidth * 0.09;

                        //static css
                        $('#bigPopWrap').css('max-width', winWidth);
                        $('#bigPopWrap img').css('max-width', winWidth);

                        while(theSource) {
                            if( n=theSource.indexOf("Vertical/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    //dynamic css
                                    $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', winWidth*0.25);
                                    $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', 'auto');

                                    //set some vars..
                                    var OMG = $('#bigPopWrap img').width();
                                    var tipPoint = winWidth*0.68;

                                    //when window is too small to contain full size image
                                    while ( OMG > tipPoint ) {
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').animate({
                                                marginLeft: '0'
                                        }, 500 );
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', '0');
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').animate({
                                                margin: '0'
                                        }, 500 );
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', '0');
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    while ( OMG < tipPoint ) {
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').stop(true);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', winWidth*0.25);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').stop(true);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', 'auto');
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                            }// end vertical

                            if( n=theSource.indexOf("Horizontal/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    //dynamic css
                                    $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', winWidth*0.1);
                                    $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', 'auto');

                                    //set some vars..
                                    var OMG = $('#bigPopWrap img').width();
                                    var tipPoint = winWidth*0.83;

                                    //when window is too small to contain full size image
                                    while ( OMG > tipPoint ) {
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').animate({
                                                marginLeft: '0'
                                        }, 500 );
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', '0');
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').animate({
                                                margin: '0'
                                        }, 500 );
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', '0');
                                        // $('#bigPopWrap img').stop(true,true);
                                        // $('#bigPopWrap').stop(true,true);
                                        // $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', '0');
                                        // $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', '0');
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    while ( OMG < tipPoint ) {
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').stop(true);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', winWidth*0.1);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').stop(true);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', 'auto');
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                            }// end horizontal

                            if( n=theSource.indexOf("Pano/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    //dynamic css
                                    $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', winWidth*0.065);
                                    $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', 'auto');

                                    //set some vars..
                                    var OMG = $('#bigPopWrap img').width();
                                    var tipPoint = winWidth*0.868;

                                    //when window is too small to contain full size image
                                    while ( OMG > tipPoint ) {
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').animate({
                                                marginLeft: '0'
                                        }, 500 );
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', '0');
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').animate({
                                                margin: '0'
                                        }, 500 );
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', '0');
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    while ( OMG < tipPoint ) {
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').stop(true);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', winWidth*0.065);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').stop(true);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', 'auto');
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                            }// end pano

                            if( n=theSource.indexOf("Pano-Tall/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    //dynamic css
                                    $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', winWidth*0.07);
                                    $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', 'auto');

                                    //set some vars..
                                    var OMG = $('#bigPopWrap img').width();
                                    var tipPoint = winWidth*0.864;

                                    //when window is too small to contain full size image
                                    while ( OMG > tipPoint ) {
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').animate({
                                                marginLeft: '0'
                                        }, 500 );
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', '0');
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').animate({
                                                margin: '0'
                                        }, 500 );
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', '0');
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    while ( OMG < tipPoint ) {
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').stop(true);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', winWidth*0.07);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').stop(true);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', 'auto');
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                            }// end panotall

                            if( n=theSource.indexOf("Pano-Vert/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    //dynamic css
                                    $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', winWidth*0.38);
                                    $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', 'auto');

                                    //set some vars..
                                    var OMG = $('#bigPopWrap img').width();
                                    var tipPoint = winWidth*0.5;

                                    //when window is too small to contain full size image
                                    while ( OMG > tipPoint ) {
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').animate({
                                                marginLeft: '0'
                                        }, 500 );
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', '0');
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').animate({
                                                margin: '0'
                                        }, 500 );
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', '0');
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    while ( OMG < tipPoint ) {
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').stop(true);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap img').css('margin-left', winWidth*0.38);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').stop(true);
                                        $('#bigPopWrap').css('margin', 'auto');
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                            }//end panovert

                            return;
                        }//end while
                    }// end function bigImageResizer


                    bigImageResizer(actualCurrent);
                    $(window).resize(function() {
                        bigImageResizer(actualCurrent);
                    });
                    $('.galleria-images').click(function () {
                        bigImageResizer(actualCurrent);
                    });

                });// end bind Galleria.IMAGE

            }// end extend function(options)

        });

    Galleria.ready(function(options) {
        // this.bind('loadfinish', function(e) {
            // $('.galleria-image').scale();
        // });

        this.bind('image', function(e) {
            this.lazyLoadChunks( 3, 200 );
            // this.scale();
            // $('#galleria').scale();
            // this.joshScale();
            // refreshImage(this);
        }); 

        this.bind('thumbnail', function(e) {
            function thumbResizer() {

                //container height
                var containerHeight = $('.galleria-thumbnails').height();
                $(window).resize(function() {
                    containerHeight = $('.galleria-thumbnails').height();
                });

                //the array
                var thumbIMGS = $('.galleria-thumbnails').find('img');

                //iterate through it
                $.each(
                    thumbIMGS,
                        function( intIndex, objValue ){

                            //thumbnail source
                            var theThumbSource = $(objValue).attr('src').replace('thumbs','sized');
                            // alert(theThumbSource);
                            // var theThumbSource = $(objValue).attr('src');

                            //modify width based on thumbnail source
                            if( n=theThumbSource.indexOf("Pano-Vert/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    // alert('pano-vert');
                                    $(objValue).parent().css('width', '0.175%');
                                }
                            }
                            if( n=theThumbSource.indexOf("Vertical/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    // alert('vert');
                                    $(objValue).parent().css('width', '0.39%');
                                }
                            }
                            if( n=theThumbSource.indexOf("Horizontal/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    // alert('horiz');
                                    $(objValue).parent().css('width', '0.6%');
                                }
                            }
                            if( n=theThumbSource.indexOf("Pano-Tall/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    // alert('pano-tall');
                                    $(objValue).parent().css('width', '0.8%');
                                }
                            }
                            if( n=theThumbSource.indexOf("Pano/") ) {
                                if(n!==-1) {
                                    // alert('pano');
                                    $(objValue).parent().css('width', '1.27%');
                                }
                            }
                    }//end function
                );//end each
            }// end function thumbResizer

            thumbResizer();

        });// end bind 'thumbnail'

        //one solution. breaks scalability
            // this.next();
            // this.prev();

        //another solution. breaks scalability
            // this.show(1);
            // this.show(0);

        //another solution. breaks scalability. what if I force rescale?
            $('.galleria-image-nav-right').click();
            $('.galleria-image-nav-left').click();

            //force rescale
            // this.bind('image', function(d) {
                // // this.lazyLoadChunks( 3, 200 );
                // $(window).resize(function() {
                    // this.scale();
                // });
            // });

        // $('.galleria-image-nav-right').attr('id', 'galleria-image-nav-right');
        // $('.galleria-image-nav-left').attr('id', 'galleria-image-nav-left');

    });// end galleria.ready
    Galleria.run('#galleria',{


    });
```

Oh, and if you're wondering, how does a problem with thumbnail scrolling even come up? The function above, thumbResizer, is the culprit -- we have five different orientations of images that go in the thumbnail browser and they are all viewable at the same time. That function scales them to fit the height of the thumbnails container div.

Also, I am not using separate thumbnails, but in fact I am actually faking it to make galleria look for thumbnails in a folder called "poop" which doesn't exist, and it says "oops, can't find it" and just uses the main image for each thumbnail, scaled down. We did this to combat the load time of Galleria, so it becomes active and clickable immediately rather than grayed out and unworkable for 8 minutes while it loads 200 rather large images at a time. Please don't say "well, you shouldn't be doing that!" Trust me, I know. My employer, however, doesn't, and absolutely wants it done that way.

Might as well write a book at this point.. :)

Thanks!

edit: forgot to mention -- while the this.scale() code does fix the scalability when it's finished loading, if you click to the next image over, it doesn't scale at all. AND, if we don't call this.scale() at all (reverting back to the previous problem of the main image not rescaling), and we click the next image over, it rescales properly. So there seems to be some kind of discrepancy between a user click and simulating a click..

Comment: Maybe a daft question but can't you use a CSS directive to scale the thumbnails to fit the height of their container div rather than doing this in javascript?

Comment: Yes, but I have different thumbnail sizes -- my js catches what they are and scales them. I could add classes rather than declare CSS in the javascript, but it's more code to remove and add class each time. Besides, it's no different -- if I do it in CSS the same problem happens, since in the end it's CSS either way I do it. Or am I misunderstanding what you mean by "directive"..?

Comment: By "directive", I just mean an entry in a stylesheet. If you want the thumbnails always to be 100% the height of their container, then `#container img { height: 100%; }` will manage that aspect and providing no width is set, either in the stylesheet or in javascript, then each image's width will be decided automatically to maintain its aspect ratio.

Comment: My God.. you've helped me solve it in a far less convoluted way than I was able to imagine. I hadn't done that because I had set the widths of each thumbnail image, so I knew that height:100% wouldn't work properly. I'd already thought of it.. but you suggesting it and saying that the width needs to be blank made me realize, duhhhh, why did I have the width set in the first place? Problem solved.. thank you sir!

Comment: I'm new to this, so I don't know how to give you the rep/credit you deserve, where do I do that?

Comment: Josh - Phew! Glad to be of assistance. If I post that as an answer, maybe you could accept it. There's nothing like big green Stackoverflow tick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the thumbnails always to be 100% the height of their container, then ...

```
#container img { height: 100%; }
```

... will manage that aspect and providing no width is set, either in the stylesheet or in javascript, then each image's width will be decided automatically to maintain its aspect ratio.

Nice and simple, and several lines of troublesome javascript can be deleted.